# Woocommerce get value from Checkout Paypal fields

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I wanna get the value from the field in Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout > Paypal, for example the title field. I have tried the following code

```
echo get_option('woocommerce_paypal_title');
```

But it does not show anything, but when I visit the page, it already have value "Paypal", is there any way I can retrieve the value? Please help, thanks.

Comment: You want to get title of paypal page? or title from last page of checkout?

Comment: I am building new payment method using woocommerce, and in one of the fields, I wanna get the value of it using get_option function, then use the value to communicate with the payment gateway, I am currently having problem getting the value using get_option, I already looked in woocommerce documents but cannot find any way to do from coding wise, maybe you could help me, pointing me to right direction? Many thanks.